# A function 'LOOKUPVALUE' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have an employee table with date.
This line of code is not working

```
Report[TransactionDate] >= LOOKUPVALUE('Exec Excep'[From],'Exec Excep'[Employee],Report[Employee])
```

I need to compare two dates for the employee. 'Exec Excep'[From] - this is the date column I'm trying to lookup.
Here's the whole code

```
Exec_Hours = CALCULATE([Eng_Hours]
//,Report[Employee] in VALUES(Engagement_New[Engagement Partner])
,Report[Rank_ActivityType] in {"Partner","Executive Director","Associate Director","Senior Manager","Manager"} ||
(Report[Employee] in VALUES('Exec Excep'[Employee])
//&& Report[TransactionDate] in Values('Exec Excep'[From])
&& Report[TransactionDate] >= LOOKUPVALUE('Exec Excep'[From],'Exec Excep'[Employee],Report[Employee])
)
) - [EQR_Hours]
```

I tried to wrap up the criteria in FILTER function but it's not working

Comment: try using a variable for your lookupvalue. For example
Exec_Hours = 
var dateLookup = [insert your lookup value code here]
return
[insert calcaulte code here, and use dateLookup variable where you have lookupvalue]

Comment: @zach the thing is that lookupvalue should be inside calculate. i think if i take out lookup to a variable before calculate it will always return me the first value of Report[Employee]